# access index of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code:

```
function Todo(id, task, who, dueDate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.task = task;
    this.who = who;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.done = false;
}

var todos = new Array();

window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
    submitButton.onclick = getFormData;
    var searchButton = document.getElementById("button");
    searchButton.onclick = search;
}

//function creates objects    

function search() {
      for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
         var todoObj = todos[i].who;
         console.log(todoObj[0]);
        }
    }
```

Two of the objects that I have created have the values "jane" and "scott" for who. What this returns in the console is first "j" and then "s". So it's accessing the first letter in both objects. When I type in just console.log(todoObj); it returns "jane" and "scott". I need to be able to access each name individually though. How can I do this?

Comment: I dont understand the question. You are accessing each one individually.

Comment: `var todoObj = todos[i]; console.log(todoObj.who);`

Comment: sorry I was not clear. I'm adding several objects to the array todos that all have "who" as one of their parameters. So I'm trying to access each name individually, not each letter.

Comment: have you tried this or @the system's code or in fact most of the other answers?

Comment: @user2084813: You can't access object properties by index if that's what you mean. Objects are an unordered collection of key/value pairs.

Comment: @user2084813: in addition to the comment above, you are instead trying to access the string object todos[i].who[0] - which is a first letter of the name

Answer (score 2):

```
todos = [ { who:"jane", ...}, {...} ]
todos[i] = { who:"jane", ...}
todos[i].who = "jane"
todos[i].who[0] = 'j'
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the index. You already have the value.

```
 console.log(todoObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are acessing the first `console.log(todoObj[0])`, so will appear "f" or "s"

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
var todoObj = todos[i].who;
```

you put the who field of the current object to the todoObj. So, the todoObj[1] is equal to the first block of the who array.
If you want to handle the whole object do :

```
var todoObj = todos[i]
```

and get the name with

```
 todoObj.who
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var todoObj = todos[i].who; // returns the string jane or scott depending on the index
console.log(todoObj[0]); // will print out the first character of the string assigned in todoObj
```

what you need to do is

```
var todoObj = todos[i]; // returns the Todo object
console.log(todoObj.who);
```